# python AsyncIO for UDP send/receive server?

Tags: python, asynchronous, udp, eventlet

Can someone recommend a framework that uses python & eventlet to handle a simple but fast UDP  receive/ack server?

Note:  I don't want to use twisted.

Comment: I think twisted is your best bet.. you can also try "Zymb" http://eblong.com/zarf/zymb/index.html